# I want to change a method in a code I imported using 'import cv2'

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I imported cv2 and there is a function that I want to change (the predict function).
I tried to see the code of cv2 in my computer but I couldn't see the code - hence I couldn't change it...
Do you know how can I alter an imported code?

Comment: The code's on [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv). The python bindings of OpenCV are just a thin wrapper around the C++ API. Any meaningful changes to the functionality would need to be done in C++ and the whole library rebuilt. What are you actually trying to achieve by this (what's the root problem)?

Comment: There is the 'predict' function that takes an image of a previously detected face and returns a matching label of it. I am attempting to change the function so it will return more then one label because sometimes I need to know few predictions instead of just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in python are objects so you can replace variable representing function and override it e.g

```
import foo

def my_function():
     # do something
     pass

foo.function = my_function
```

Comment: oh wow that's something new to me, but I can't look at the existing code of the method - I want to change a part of the method so I would prefer to edit the existing method instead of replacing it. When I search for the code in the file explorer all I can see is the __init__.py file .

Comment: You can try to do `import inspect; inspect.get_source(function_obj)` that will show you code of the method. Also you can find it on the github like Dan Masek said.

Comment: I don't understand what is the 'function_obj' you said?

Comment: It's the function reference e.g. `import foo; import inspect; inspect.get_source(foo.function)`

Comment: when I try to do `import inspect;
import cv2;
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
print inspect.getsource(face_recognizer.predict)` then i get an error: `TypeError: <built-in method predict of cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer object at 0x0000000002E54F50> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object`

Comment: Ah there is no way to inspect the function because it's of type built-in function. Probably as Dan said before it's written in cpp and compiled in module

Comment: so how can I look at the method? I can't find it ot github

Comment: Yep, it's a single binary module, basically a renamed shared library (DLL/so/...). Even the bindings are generated automatically during the build process. Any modifications would require decent experience with C++ and ability to navigate through (and grok) a sizable (and complex) codebase.

Comment: So if I can't modify it straight from the source code, do I have any other option to change the behavior of some method?

Comment: @YotamHammer I'd suggest posting a concrete question about the specific problem you're trying to solve (recognising multiple faces), along with a [mcve], sample input and description of how this fails. It's quite possible there may be other approaches than the one your mind is set on right now. Once we can see the exact code in question, we can also point you to the right location to find the implementation (it is possible that it's part of opencv_contrib, which lives in a separate repository).

Comment: OK. Thank you Dan and thank you everyone for the responses! see you in my upcoming post ;)